# Explaining Kronecker delta from operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

I'm trying to prove the relation for angular momentum operator.

$[\hat{L}_i,\hat{r}_j] = i\hbar \sum_{k} \epsilon_{ijk} \hat{r}_k $

$ [\hat{L}_i,\hat{r}_l]$

= $ \sum_{jk} \epsilon_{ijk} [\hat{r}_j\hat{p}_k, \hat{r}_l]$

= $\sum_{jk} \epsilon_{ijk} \{{\hat{r}_j [\hat{p}_k, \hat{r}_l] + [ \hat{r}_j, \hat{r}_l]\hat{p}_k} \}$

= $ -i\hbar \sum_{jk} \epsilon_{ijk} \hat{r}_j \delta_{kl} $

Can someone explain how do I get Kronecker delta from the equation above?

Comment: Can you explain the physical context a little? What do the symbols mean and what are you summing over?

Comment: @BySymmetry Added.

Answer (score 2):

We have the commutator bracket
$$ [\hat{p}_k, \hat{r}_l] =-\iota \hbar \delta_{kl}$$
which means that, in 3-dim space i.e. for space coordinates $(\hat{r}_1=\hat{x},\hat{r}_2=\hat{y},\hat{r}_3=\hat{z})$ and momentum coordinates $(\hat{p}_1=\hat{p}_x,\hat{p}_2=\hat{p}_y,\hat{p}_3=\hat{p}_z)$; we have

$$\hat{r}_1 \hat{p}_1 - \hat{p}_1 \hat{r}_1 =-\iota \hbar$$
$$\hat{r}_2 \hat{p}_2 - \hat{p}_2 \hat{r}_2 =-\iota \hbar$$
$$\hat{r}_3 \hat{p}_3 - \hat{p}_3 \hat{r}_3 =-\iota \hbar$$

Here, $\delta_{kl}=1$, since index k=l.

and **all** the other dissimilar pairings like

$$\hat{r}_1 \hat{p}_2 - \hat{p}_2 \hat{r}_1 =0$$
because, by definition $\delta_{kl}=0$, when $k \neq l$.

The bracket
$$[ \hat{r}_j, \hat{r}_l]=0$$
because the operator $\hat{r}$ commutes with itself for all the components. Put these results back into your equation
$$\sum_{jk} \epsilon_{ijk} \{{\hat{r}_j \,\,\mathbf{[\hat{p}_k, \hat{r}_l]}} + \mathbf{[ \hat{r}_j, \hat{r}_l]}\,\,\,\hat{p}_k \}$$ and see it solves.

Comment: understood. Thank you.^^

Answer (score 1):

You get the delta precisely from the canonical commutation relation of quantum mechanics
$$
[\hat{p_k},\hat{r_l}]=-i\hbar \delta_{kl} \qquad [\hat{p_k},\hat{p_l}]=0 \qquad [\hat{r_k},\hat{r_l}]=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\sum_kA_k\delta_{kl}=A_l$ to get $[L_i,\,r_l]=-i\hbar\sum_j\epsilon_{ijl}r_j=i\hbar\sum_j\epsilon_{ilj}r_j=i\hbar\sum_j\epsilon_{ijl}r_l$, where the last $=$ relabels dummy indices.